# Convert index.pug to Vue Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, tailwind-css, pug

I have a pug file called `index.pug` like so, also comprising tailwind css classes.

```
html(lang="en")
    head
        title Page title
        meta(charset="utf-8")
        meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no")
        link(rel="preconnect", href="https://fonts.gstatic.com")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="css/tailwind/tailwind.min.css")
        link(rel="icon", type="image/png", sizes="32x32", href="shuffle-for-tailwind.png")
        script(src="js/main.js")
    body(class="antialiased bg-body text-body font-body")
        div(class="")
            section(class="bg-white")
                nav(class="flex justify-between p-6 px-4")
                    div(class="flex justify-between items-center w-full")
                        div(class="xl:w-1/3")
                            a(class="block max-w-max", href="#")
                                img(class="h-8", src="flex-ui-assets/logos/flex-ui-green-light.svg", alt="")
                        div(class="hidden xl:block xl:w-1/3")
                            ul(class="flex justify-center")
                                li(class="mr-12")
                                    a(class="text-coolGray-500 hover:text-coolGray-900 font-medium", href="#") Product
                                li(class="mr-12")
                                    a(class="text-coolGray-500 hover:text-coolGray-900 font-medium", href="#") Features
                                li(class="mr-12")
                                    a(class="text-coolGray-500 hover:text-coolGray-900 font-medium", href="#") Resources
                                li
                                    a(class="text-coolGray-500 hover:text-coolGray-900 font-medium", href="#") Pricing
                        div(class="hidden xl:block xl:w-1/3")
                            div(class="flex items-center justify-end")
                                a(class="inline-block py-2 px-4 mr-2 leading-5 text-coolGray-500 hover:text-coolGray-900 bg-transparent font-medium rounded-md", href="#") Log In
                                a(class="inline-block py-2 px-4 text-sm leading-5 text-green-50 bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-600 font-medium focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-500 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md", href="#") Sign Up
                    button(class="navbar-burger self-center xl:hidden")
                        svg(width="35", height="35", viewbox="0 0 32 32", fill="none", xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
                            rect(class="text-coolGray-50", width="32", height="32", rx="6", fill="currentColor")
                            path(class="text-coolGray-500", d="M7 12H25C25.2652 12 25.5196 11.8946 25.7071 11.7071C25.8946 11.5196 26 11.2652 26 11C26 10.7348 25.8946 10.4804 25.7071 10.2929C25.5196 10.1054 25.2652 10 25 10H7C6.73478 10 6.48043 10.1054 6.29289 10.2929C6.10536 10.4804 6 10.7348 6 11C6 11.2652 6.10536 11.5196 6.29289 11.7071C6.48043 11.8946 6.73478 12 7 12ZM25 15H7C6.73478 15 6.48043 15.1054 6.29289 15.2929C6.10536 15.4804 6 15.7348 6 16C6 16.2652 6.10536 16.5196 6.29289 16.7071C6.48043 16.8946 6.73478 17 7 17H25C25.2652 17 25.5196 16.8946 25.7071 16.7071C25.8946 16.5196 26 16.2652 26 16C26 15.7348 25.8946 15.4804 25.7071 15.2929C25.5196 15.1054 25.2652 15 25 15ZM25 20H7C6.73478 20 6.48043 20.1054 6.29289 20.2929C6.10536 20.4804 6 20.7348 6 21C6 21.2652 6.10536 21.5196 6.29289 21.7071C6.48043 21.8946 6.73478 22 7 22H25C25.2652 22 25.5196 21.8946 25.7071 21.7071C25.8946 21.5196 26 21.2652 26 21C26 20.7348 25.8946 20.4804 25.7071 20.2929C25.5196 20.1054 25.2652 20 25 20Z", fill="currentColor")
                div(class="navbar-menu hidden fixed top-0 left-0 z-50 w-full h-full bg-coolGray-900 bg-opacity-50")
                    div(class="fixed top-0 left-0 bottom-0 w-full w-4/6 max-w-xs bg-white")
                        nav(class="relative p-6 h-full overflow-y-auto")
                            div(class="flex flex-col justify-between h-full")
                                a(class="inline-block", href="#")
                                    img(class="h-8", src="flex-ui-assets/logos/flex-ui-green-light.svg", alt="")
                                ul(class="py-6")
                                    li
                                        a(class="block py-3 px-4 text-coolGray-500 hover:text-coolGray-900 font-medium hover:bg-coolGray-50 rounded-md", href="#") Product
                                    li
                                        a(class="block py-3 px-4 text-coolGray-500 hover:text-coolGray-900 font-medium hover:bg-coolGray-50 rounded-md", href="#") Features
                                    li
                                        a(class="block py-3 px-4 text-coolGray-500 hover:text-coolGray-900 font-medium hover:bg-coolGray-50 rounded-md", href="#") Pricing
                                    li
                                        a(class="block py-3 px-4 text-coolGray-500 hover:text-coolGray-900 font-medium hover:bg-coolGray-50 rounded-md", href="#") Resources
                                div(class="flex flex-wrap")
                                    div(class="w-full mb-2")
                                        a(class="inline-block py-2 px-4 w-full text-sm leading-5 text-coolGray-500 hover:text-coolGray-900 bg-transparent font-medium text-center rounded-md", href="#") Log In
                                    div(class="w-full")
                                        a(class="inline-block py-2 px-4 w-full text-sm leading-5 text-white bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-600 font-medium text-center focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-500 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md", href="#") Sign Up
                        a(class="navbar-close absolute top-5 p-4 right-3", href="#")
                            svg(width="12", height="12", viewbox="0 0 12 12", fill="none", xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
                                path(d="M6.94004 6L11.14 1.80667C11.2656 1.68113 11.3361 1.51087 11.3361 1.33333C11.3361 1.1558 11.2656 0.985537 11.14 0.860002C11.0145 0.734466 10.8442 0.66394 10.6667 0.66394C10.4892 0.66394 10.3189 0.734466 10.1934 0.860002L6.00004 5.06L1.80671 0.860002C1.68117 0.734466 1.51091 0.663941 1.33337 0.663941C1.15584 0.663941 0.985576 0.734466 0.860041 0.860002C0.734505 0.985537 0.66398 1.1558 0.66398 1.33333C0.66398 1.51087 0.734505 1.68113 0.860041 1.80667L5.06004 6L0.860041 10.1933C0.797555 10.2553 0.747959 10.329 0.714113 10.4103C0.680267 10.4915 0.662842 10.5787 0.662842 10.6667C0.662842 10.7547 0.680267 10.8418 0.714113 10.9231C0.747959 11.0043 0.797555 11.078 0.860041 11.14C0.922016 11.2025 0.99575 11.2521 1.07699 11.2859C1.15823 11.3198 1.24537 11.3372 1.33337 11.3372C1.42138 11.3372 1.50852 11.3198 1.58976 11.2859C1.671 11.2521 1.74473 11.2025 1.80671 11.14L6.00004 6.94L10.1934 11.14C10.2554 11.2025 10.3291 11.2521 10.4103 11.2859C10.4916 11.3198 10.5787 11.3372 10.6667 11.3372C10.7547 11.3372 10.8419 11.3198 10.9231 11.2859C11.0043 11.2521 11.0781 11.2025 11.14 11.14C11.2025 11.078 11.2521 11.0043 11.286 10.9231C11.3198 10.8418 11.3372 10.7547 11.3372 10.6667C11.3372 10.5787 11.3198 10.4915 11.286 10.4103C11.2521 10.329 11.2025 10.2553 11.14 10.1933L6.94004 6Z", fill="#556987")
            section(class="py-20 xl:py-24 bg-white overflow-hidden", style="background-image: url('flex-ui-assets/elements/pattern-white.svg'); background-position: center;")
                div(class="container px-4 mx-auto")
                    div(class="text-center")
                        span(class="inline-block py-px px-2 mb-4 text-xs leading-5 text-green-500 bg-green-100 font-medium uppercase rounded-9xl") Pricing
                        h3(class="mb-4 text-3xl md:text-5xl text-coolGray-900 font-bold tracking-tighter") Flexible pricing plan for your startup
                        p(class="mb-6 text-lg md:text-xl text-coolGray-500 font-medium") Pricing that scales with your business immediately.
                        div(class="flex mb-12 mx-auto max-w-max border border-coolGray-200 overflow-hidden rounded-md shadow-lg")
                            a(class="py-3 px-5 text-sm text-green-500 bg-white font-medium border-r border-coolGray-200", href="#") Billed Monthly
                            a(class="py-3 px-5 text-sm text-coolGray-500 bg-coolGray-50 font-medium", href="#") Billed Annually
                    div(class="flex flex-wrap justify-center -mx-4")
                        div(class="w-full md:w-1/2 p-4")
                            div(class="flex flex-col pt-8 pb-8 bg-coolGray-50 rounded-md shadow-md hover:scale-105 transition duration-500")
                                div(class="flex items-center justify-between px-8")
                                    div
                                        h3(class="text-2xl md:text-3xl text-coolGray-800 font-semibold tracking-tighter") Basic plan
                                        p(class="text-coolGray-400 font-medium") For bigger teams
                                    div
                                        span(class="relative -top-10 right-1 text-3xl text-coolGray-900 font-bold") $
                                        |                     
                                        span(class="text-6xl md:text-7xl text-coolGray-900 font-semibold tracking-tighter") 99
                                        |                     
                                        span(class="inline-block ml-1 text-coolGray-500 font-semibold") /mo
                                div(class="border-b border-coolGray-100")
                                ul(class="self-start px-8 pt-8 pb-16")
                                    li(class="flex items-center mb-4 text-coolGray-500 font-medium")
                                        img(class="mr-3", src="flex-ui-assets/elements/pricing/checkbox-green.svg")
                                        span Access to all features
                                    li(class="flex items-center mb-4 text-coolGray-500 font-medium")
                                        img(class="mr-3", src="flex-ui-assets/elements/pricing/checkbox-green.svg")
                                        span Assisted onboarding support
                                    li(class="flex items-center mb-4 text-coolGray-500 font-medium")
                                        img(class="mr-3", src="flex-ui-assets/elements/pricing/checkbox-green.svg")
                                        span CPM Overage: Unlimited
                                    li(class="flex items-center text-coolGray-500 font-medium")
                                        img(class="mr-3", src="flex-ui-assets/elements/pricing/checkbox-green.svg")
                                        span Program reviews 1x a month
                                div(class="border-b border-coolGray-100")
                                div(class="px-8 pt-8")
                                    a(class="inline-block py-4 px-7 w-full text-base md:text-lg leading-6 text-green-50 font-medium text-center bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-600 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-500 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm", href="#") Get Started Now
                        div(class="w-full md:w-1/2 p-4")
                            div(class="flex flex-col pt-8 pb-8 bg-coolGray-50 rounded-md shadow-md hover:scale-105 transition duration-500")
                                div(class="flex items-center justify-between px-8")
                                    div
                                        h3(class="text-2xl md:text-3xl text-coolGray-800 font-semibold tracking-tighter") Lifetime
                                        p(class="text-coolGray-400 font-medium") Unlimited possibilities
                                    div
                                        span(class="relative -top-10 right-1 text-3xl text-coolGray-900 font-bold") $
                                        |                     
                                        span(class="text-6xl md:text-7xl text-coolGray-900 font-semibold tracking-tighter") 189
                                        |                     
                                        span(class="inline-block ml-1 text-coolGray-500 font-semibold") /mo
                                div(class="border-b border-coolGray-100")
                                ul(class="self-start px-8 pt-8 pb-16")
                                    li(class="flex items-center mb-4 text-coolGray-500 font-medium")
                                        img(class="mr-3", src="flex-ui-assets/elements/pricing/checkbox-green.svg")
                                        span Access to all features
                                    li(class="flex items-center mb-4 text-coolGray-500 font-medium")
                                        img(class="mr-3", src="flex-ui-assets/elements/pricing/checkbox-green.svg")
                                        span Assisted onboarding support
                                    li(class="flex items-center mb-4 text-coolGray-500 font-medium")
                                        img(class="mr-3", src="flex-ui-assets/elements/pricing/checkbox-green.svg")
                                        span CPM Overage: Unlimited
                                    li(class="flex items-center text-coolGray-500 font-medium")
                                        img(class="mr-3", src="flex-ui-assets/elements/pricing/checkbox-green.svg")
                                        span Program reviews 1x a month
                                div(class="border-b border-coolGray-100")
                                div(class="px-8 pt-8")
                                    a(class="inline-block py-4 px-7 w-full text-base md:text-lg leading-6 text-green-50 font-medium text-center bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-600 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-500 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm", href="#") Get Started Now
            section(class="pt-24 bg-white", style="background-image: url('flex-ui-assets/elements/pattern-white.svg'); background-position: center;")
                div(class="container px-4 mx-auto")
                    div(class="max-w-4xl mb-16")
                        span(class="inline-block py-px px-2 mb-4 text-xs leading-5 text-green-500 bg-green-100 font-medium rounded-full shadow-sm") FAQ
                        h2(class="mb-4 text-4xl md:text-5xl leading-tight text-coolGray-900 font-bold tracking-tighter") Frequently Asked Questions
                        p(class="text-lg md:text-xl text-coolGray-500 font-medium") Flex is the only saas business platform that lets you run your business on one platform, seamlessly across all digital channels.
                    div(class="flex flex-wrap pb-16 -mx-4")
                        div(class="w-full md:w-1/2 xl:w-1/3 px-4 mb-8")
                            div(class="md:max-w-xs")
                                div(class="inline-flex mb-6 items-center justify-center w-12 h-12 rounded-full bg-green-500")
                                    img(src="flex-ui-assets/elements/faq/shield-icon.svg", alt="")
                                h3(class="mb-6 text-xl text-coolGray-900 font-bold") What shipping options do you have?
                                p(class="text-coolGray-500 font-medium") For USA domestic orders we offer FedEx and USPS shipping. Contact us via email to learn more.
                        div(class="w-full md:w-1/2 xl:w-1/3 px-4 mb-8")
                            div(class="md:max-w-xs")
                                div(class="inline-flex mb-6 items-center justify-center w-12 h-12 rounded-full bg-green-500")
                                    img(src="flex-ui-assets/elements/faq/shield-icon.svg", alt="")
                                h3(class="mb-6 text-xl text-coolGray-900 font-bold") What payment methods do you accept?
                                p(class="text-coolGray-500 font-medium") Any method of payments acceptable by you. For example: We accept MasterCard, Visa.
                        div(class="w-full md:w-1/2 xl:w-1/3 px-4 mb-8")
                            div(class="md:max-w-xs")
                                div(class="inline-flex mb-6 items-center justify-center w-12 h-12 rounded-full bg-green-500")
                                    img(src="flex-ui-assets/elements/faq/shield-icon.svg", alt="")
                                h3(class="mb-6 text-xl text-coolGray-900 font-bold") How long does it take to ship my order?
                                p(class="text-coolGray-500 font-medium") Orders are usually shipped within 1-2 business days after placing the order.
                        div(class="w-full md:w-1/2 xl:w-1/3 px-4 mb-8 xl:mb-0")
                            div(class="md:max-w-xs")
                                div(class="inline-flex mb-6 items-center justify-center w-12 h-12 rounded-full bg-green-500")
                                    img(src="flex-ui-assets/elements/faq/shield-icon.svg", alt="")
                                h3(class="mb-6 text-xl text-coolGray-900 font-bold") What shipping options do you have?
                                p(class="text-coolGray-500 font-medium") For USA domestic orders we offer FedEx and USPS shipping. Contact us via email to learn more.
                        div(class="w-full md:w-1/2 xl:w-1/3 px-4 mb-8 md:mb-0")
                            div(class="md:max-w-xs")
                                div(class="inline-flex mb-6 items-center justify-center w-12 h-12 rounded-full bg-green-500")
                                    img(src="flex-ui-assets/elements/faq/shield-icon.svg", alt="")
                                h3(class="mb-6 text-xl text-coolGray-900 font-bold") What payment methods do you accept?
                                p(class="text-coolGray-500 font-medium") Any method of payments acceptable by you. For example: We accept MasterCard, Visa.
                        div(class="w-full md:w-1/2 xl:w-1/3 px-4")
                            div(class="md:max-w-xs")
                                div(class="inline-flex mb-6 items-center justify-center w-12 h-12 rounded-full bg-green-500")
                                    img(src="flex-ui-assets/elements/faq/shield-icon.svg", alt="")
                                h3(class="mb-6 text-xl text-coolGray-900 font-bold") How long does it take to ship my order?
                                p(class="text-coolGray-500 font-medium") Orders are usually shipped within 1-2 business days after placing the order.
                    div(class="relative -mb-40 py-16 px-4 md:px-8 lg:px-16 bg-coolGray-800 rounded-md overflow-hidden")
                        img(class="absolute top-0 left-0 h-full w-full object-cover", src="flex-ui-assets/elements/pattern-dark.svg", alt="")
                        div(class="relative max-w-max mx-auto text-center")
                            h3(class="mb-2 text-2xl md:text-5xl leading-tight font-bold text-white tracking-tighter") Have any additional questions?
                            p(class="mb-6 text-base md:text-xl text-coolGray-400") Flex is a Small SaaS Business. Flex isn’t a traditional company.
                            a(class="inline-flex items-center justify-center px-7 py-3 h-14 w-full md:w-auto mb-2 md:mb-0 md:mr-4 text-lg leading-7 text-green-50 bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-600 font-medium focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-500 focus:ring-opacity-50 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm", href="#") Get in touch
                div(class="h-64 bg-green-500")
            section(class="bg-white overflow-hidden", style="background-image: url('flex-ui-assets/elements/pattern-white.svg'); background-position: center;")
                div(class="container px-4 mx-auto")
                    div(class="flex flex-wrap lg:items-center pt-24 pb-12 -mx-4")
                        div(class="w-full md:w-2/3 px-4")
                            a(class="block mb-12 max-w-max", href="#")
                                img(class="h-8", src="flex-ui-assets/logos/flex-ui-green-light.svg", alt="")
                            div(class="mb-12 md:mb-0 flex flex-wrap -mx-3 md:-mx-6")
                                div(class="w-full md:w-auto p-3 md:py-0 md:px-6")
                                    a(class="inline-block text-coolGray-400 hover:text-coolGray-500 font-medium", href="#") Product
                                div(class="w-full md:w-auto p-3 md:py-0 md:px-6")
                                    a(class="inline-block text-coolGray-400 hover:text-coolGray-500 font-medium", href="#") Features
                                div(class="w-full md:w-auto p-3 md:py-0 md:px-6")
                                    a(class="inline-block text-coolGray-400 hover:text-coolGray-500 font-medium", href="#") Pricing
                                div(class="w-full md:w-auto p-3 md:py-0 md:px-6")
                                    a(class="inline-block text-coolGray-400 hover:text-coolGray-500 font-medium", href="#") Resources
                                div(class="w-full md:w-auto p-3 md:py-0 md:px-6")
                                    a(class="inline-block text-coolGray-400 hover:text-coolGray-500 font-medium", href="#") Careers
                        div(class="w-full md:w-1/3 px-4")
                            h3(class="mb-6 text-lg font-bold text-coolGray-900") Newsletter
                            div(class="flex flex-wrap")
                                div(class="w-full lg:flex-1 py-1 lg:py-0 lg:mr-3")
                                    input(class="px-3 w-full h-12 text-coolGray-900 outline-none placeholder-coolGray-500 border border-coolGray-200 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-500 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-lg shadow-xsm", placeholder="Your email")
                                div(class="w-full lg:w-auto py-1 lg:py-0")
                                    a(class="inline-block py-4 px-5 w-full leading-4 text-green-50 font-medium text-center bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-600 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-500 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm", href="#") Subscribe
                div(class="border-b border-coolGray-100")
                div(class="container px-4 mx-auto")
                    div(class="flex flex-wrap items-center py-12 md:pb-24 -mx-4")
                        div(class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-4")
                            p(class="mb-3 md:mb-0 text-coolGray-400 font-medium") © 2021 Flex. All rights reserved.
                        div(class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-4")
                            div(class="flex flex-wrap justify-end -mx-3 md:-mx-4")
                                div(class="w-full md:w-auto p-3 md:py-0 md:px-4")
                                    a(class="inline-block text-coolGray-400 hover:text-coolGray-500 font-medium", href="#") Terms
                                div(class="w-full md:w-auto p-3 md:py-0 md:px-4")
                                    a(class="inline-block text-coolGray-400 hover:text-coolGray-500 font-medium", href="#") Privacy
                                div(class="w-full md:w-auto p-3 md:py-0 md:px-4")
                                    a(class="inline-block text-coolGray-400 hover:text-coolGray-500 font-medium", href="#") Cookies
        script(src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts")
        script(src="js/charts-demo.js")
```

I need the exact same output when it's used on the `Vue` component called Home.vue, I have no idea how to use it inside a vue component. i tried converting it into an HTML and paste it inside the  tags. But nothing seems to work. as you can see the tailwind CSS classes didn't work either when pasted to the new vue component Home.vue.
I also put the lang attribute set to pug. and also configured tailwind CSS in vue. The output just comes up unstyled and i don't know whether i am even using the pug file correctly in the Home.vue.

I am a complete beginner to vuejs. can you please help me with this? on how to put this pug file you are seeing above inside a vue component and work exactly as it should have.

Comment: Hi.  "as you can see the tailwind CSS classes didn't work either..."  As I can see where???

Comment: Also, I am not sure I understand what you have tried so far.  Let's start by completing the information:  I suppose this pug template is served via a Node.js server.  Correct?  Now tell me about your Vue project.  Is it a separate project?  Or are you trying to somehow make this pug page serve a Vue application?  Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: You can rewrite if using Vue [Render Functions](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html) or just take the generated from the template HTML and put it in the `<template>` section of your new component. Check Vue [Components](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html) for details.

Comment: @JoséRamírez Yes i am trying to serve this pug page on a vue app. This is the gdrive link to this index.pug file and its assets: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cl8nTBFfar5AcDOD_9V1N7-PhCm9hYlt/view
when you run this proj (details in readme) you will see a homepage. i want that exact same home page to show up when my Home.vue renders. i really don't know how to migrate this exactly as it is to vue.

Comment: @Tolbxela i tried that. but only thing i was able to see was unstyled HTML elements. none of the tailwind CSS styles was applied to it at all.

Comment: @JoséRamírez i created a new vue 2 proj called home-page using vue cli. and i installed tailwind & the custom styles you can see in the tailwind.config.js on the gdrive. i can see the same visual out as i saw in with index.pug.

Comment: @Matrix-eve the problem with Tailwind CSS styles has nothing to do with Vue. Check the CSS style files, if they are correctly loaded.

Comment: Do you need to still have PUG code inside the Vue component or it can be replaced with simple HTML?

Comment: @Tolbxela Yes, even if it is html its okay. but the visual output should be the same as if it was the index.pug file (in the gdrive).

Comment: I can do it in HTML without pug.

Comment: With that exact visual output. is that possible to share that in drive (removing the node_modules). I just want that home page to show up that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You should notice, that HTML Head should not be rendered in a component.

Since you have you app somewhere in the HTML Body

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

And some component cannot render the other parts of HTML.

If can work only if you have main App.vue component, which renders the whole HTML page.

`App.vue`

```
<template>    
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/tailwind/tailwind.min.css" />
        ....
        </head>
    </html>    
</template>
```

Comment: did you tried the gdrive i gave you. and tried to incorporate the index.pug version inside a file called Home.vue. if you did will it be possible to share that file after removing the node_modules on drive. i just need that page working. if i drop my mail can you reach out please.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough free time to do it. If you like to, I could help you to manage it over [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io/@tolbxela).

Comment: I would have done it. i cant even pay you. or else i could have. i really want to solve this :(